# Problems to validate a for cycle in C ++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I made this program that starts printing a small rectangle, and then prints other larger rectangles until a certain point is reached, but it is assumed that when the first cycle ends, the last for of the program would have to do the opposite, printing a larger rectangle and then printing smaller rectangles, the problem is that the program only does the first for, ignoring the second one, I don't know if I missed adding something, does anyone know what error I can have? I'm still new at programming, excuse me.

```
#include <iostream>                                                       
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h> 
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void pos(int x,int y){  
      HANDLE hcon;  
      hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  
      COORD dwPos;  
      dwPos.X = x;  
      dwPos.Y= y;  
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);  
}  

void square(int col1, int col2, int row1, int row2) //The square function is the one I use to print all the squares, just by changing the positions
{
    pos(col1,row1);
    cout << char(201);
    pos(col1,row2);
    cout << char(200);
    pos(col2,row1);
    cout << char(187);
    pos(col2,row2);
    cout << char(188);  

    for (int x = col1 + 1; x < col2; x++)
    {
        pos(x, row1);
        cout << char(205);

        pos(x, row2);
        cout << char(205);
    }
    for (int y = row1 + 1; y < row2; y++)
    {
        pos(col1,y);
        cout << char(186);

        pos(col2,y);
        cout << char(186);
    }
}

int main(){
    system("color 2E");

    int N = 22, N2 = 23;
    int x1 = 32, x2 = 33, y1 = 100, y2 = 105;
    int x3 = 4, x4 = 49, y3 = 4, y4 = 215;

    pos(30,30);
    cout << "Put the program in full screen so it can be better appreciated";
    Sleep(4000);
    system("cls");

    for (int i; i < N; i++){ //This for is responsible for printing the squares from minor to major

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);

        Sleep(200);
        square (y1, y2, x1, x2);

        y1 = y1 - 5;
        y2 = y2 + 5;
        x1 = x1 - 1;
        x2 = x2 + 1;

        cout << "\n\n\n";
    }

    system("cls");

    for (int j; j < N2; j++){ //When the screen is clean, this for would have to start printing squares from major to minor

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);

        Sleep(200);
        square (y3, y4, x3, x4);

        y3 = y3 + 4;
        y4 = y4 - 4;
        x3 = x3 + 1;
        x4 = x4 - 1;

        cout << "\n\n\n";

        system("cls");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program has Undefined Behavior because you don't initialize your for loop index variables.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment is correct. Just wonder why you didn't see the errors while compiling your program? You also might want to remove system("cls") at the end of the second for loop for better visual experience.